# Tomcat 7 skip specific folder loading from webapps

Tags: deployment, tomcat7

I am having two .war files, say webapp-A.war and webapp-B.war of two different projects. When I start tomcat, it deploys these wars and two folders are created in webapps directory i.e. webapp-A and webapp-B.

When I start tomcat both these folders are scanned and loaded. This increases the startup time of tomcat and consumes more memory. I dont want to work on both at a time but I must be able to switch between any two.

So, is there any way to skip loading of webapp-B when I am working on webapp-A considering both being present in webapps directory?

Comment: You can eventually disable automated deployment and deploy chosen app manually. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment

Answer (score 6):

When working with webapp-A, go to TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml and update the host tag with attribute 'deployIgnore' as shown below

```html
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="webapp-B">

....
</Host>
```

Start your tomcat server, webapp-B will not be deployed :)

This is my very first answer on stackoverflow btw, hope it helps, I signed up to help you.

Comment: how to use regex in deployIgnore? Here, you are only able to ignore "webapp-B"

Comment: @Gaurav see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966006/156973).