# Ignore multiple apps in deployIgnore in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to ignore multiple apps from loading in Tomcat at startup to better the startup time. Approach I want to take is from the Host tag:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="examples>
```

If I just do one app which is examples, it works fine, but I want only my application to deploy and not the other ones in webapps. On putting multiple apps, it just loads everything on start up in the webapps folder. Documentation says to provide regular expression :

[image]

I am unable to add a regular expression that will make it ignore deploying ROOT, host-manager, manager, docs, examples and docs. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: This is what I tried for regex to ignore other apps in webapps apart from mine:   (?!mycontext) .. I tried testing the regex and it does seem to just find mycontext and not others in a directory https://regex101.com/r/wZ3sM3/2  .. but on start up it still ignores regex and loads everything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Try this 
deployIgnore=".*ROOT.*|.*host.*|.*manager.*|.*docs.*|.*example.*"